# add another shape with effect on existing image overlay hover effect

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have this code: https://jsfiddle.net/e0u4sow1/6/

It works, I added a arrow beneath the text when you hover over the image. I want that arrow to slide in from the left to the center with a slow end and when you move your mouse away to slide right with a slow start. I spend 2 hours now trying many things to get this to work, but I give up. Can someone help me with this? also maybe a small explanation as to what part in the code makes the arrow slide in and out? I removed all code with arroweffect relations, so it's just the original effect with the arrow added

```css
.media {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.media__image {
  display: block;
}
.media__body {
  background: rgba(41, 128, 185, 0.7);
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3.75em 3em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
}
.media__body:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.media__body:after,
.media__body:before {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  bottom: 1em;
  content: '';
  left: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s 0.2s;
  transition: 0.6s 0.2s;
}
.media__body:before {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  left: 2em;
  right: 2em;
}
.media__body:after {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  bottom: 2em;
  top: 2em;
}
.media__body:hover:after,
.media__body:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.media__body h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.media__body p {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.arr {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.2em;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 0 2px #FFF inset;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>MR Cube</h1>
<div class="media">
  <a href="http://www.google.nl/">
    <img alt="" class="media__image" src="http://www.webwinkelsucces.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/1112625-les-outils-de-test-et-d-integration-continue-open-source.jpg" />
    <div class="media__body">
      <h1>Lees meer</h1>
      <div class="arr"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't post your try to make the animation, it's hard to explain what you did wrong.

I made the animation in the following example adding translate on the arrow and removing it on hover. The transition decalration makes the animation between both states.

```css
.media {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.media__image {
  display: block;
}
.media__body {
  background: rgba(41, 128, 185, 0.7);
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3.75em 3em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
}
.media__body:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.media__body:after,
.media__body:before {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  bottom: 1em;
  content: '';
  left: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s 0.2s;
  transition: 0.6s 0.2s;
}
.media__body:before {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  left: 2em;
  right: 2em;
}
.media__body:after {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  bottom: 2em;
  top: 2em;
}
.media__body:hover:after,
.media__body:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.media__body h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.media__body p {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.arr {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.2em;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 0 2px #FFF inset;
  transform: translateX(250px) rotate(135deg);
  transition: transform .8s ease-in;
}
.media__body:hover .arr {
  transform: translateX(0) rotate(135deg);
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="media">
  <a href="http://www.google.nl/">
    <img alt="" class="media__image" src="http://www.webwinkelsucces.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/1112625-les-outils-de-test-et-d-integration-continue-open-source.jpg" />
    <div class="media__body">
      <h1>Lees meer</h1>
      <div class="arr"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
```

*Note that you will need to add the vendor prefixes to the transition and transform properties for browser support (see canIuse for [2D transform](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) and [transitions](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions))*

I would also suggest you read up on MDN about [transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

Comment: My tries were going nowhere, at least with your added code I can see what makes it work, and that helps A LOT. Thanks!